# Receiving binary Data from a rest endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stringreader

I am new to API/Rest endpoints, so please forgive my inexperience on this topic.

I am using .net core 3.1. And i have been tasked to write an endpoint, that excepts two parameters a string and a file..

The file will be of binary data (a .bci file format, which i assume is a custom one, but all it is basically is a .txt file, that has been changed to .bci for a machine)

I need to get the file and then read the file using a stringReader and saved to a file locally. Again i am new to endpoints and reading binary data, can anyone help? i have been looking all over the internet today but with no prevail.

I know the below code is incorrect, but really struggling on this one. Any help would much be appreciated.

```
//GET: api/ProcessResultsFiles]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessResults(IFormFile file, string bench)
        {
            await ReadData(file);
            return Ok();
        }

        private static Task<byte[]> ReadData(IFormFile benchNameFile)
        {
            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(benchNameFile))
            {
                string input = null;
                while ((input = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(input);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can't use `[HttpGet]` in this scenario. Change it to `[HttpPost]`.

Comment: ok, and that will solve it?

Comment: It will put you in the right direction. Try it out and see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

From your description, I assume you want to upload the file to the Physical storage/folder, after that might be you want to download the file to local, if that is the case, you could refer the following sample:

```
    [HttpPost("upload")]
    public IActionResult Upload(List<IFormFile> formFiles, string subDirectory)
    {
        try
        {
            subDirectory = subDirectory ?? string.Empty;
            var target = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, subDirectory);

            if(!Directory.Exists(target))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(target);

            formFiles.ForEach(async file =>
            {
                if (file.Length <= 0) return;
                var filePath = Path.Combine(target, file.FileName);
                using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
            });

            return Ok("Upload success!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    [HttpPost("download")]
    public IActionResult DownLoad( string subDirectory,   string filename)
    { 
        //Build the File Path.
        string path = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, subDirectory +"/"+ filename);

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        { 
            //Read the File data into Byte Array.
            byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            //download the file.
            return File(bytes, "application/octet-stream", filename);
        }
        else
        {
            return Ok("file not exist");
        }
    }
```

The result as below:

[image]

More detail information about upload file in asp.net core, you can refer the following articles:

[Upload files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0#storage-scenarios)

[Upload And Download Multiple Files Using Web API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-and-download-multiple-files-using-web-api/)

From the above articles, when upload file, if you want to save the byte array, you can refer the following code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUploadAsync()
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await FileUpload.FormFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

        // Upload the file if less than 2 MB
        if (memoryStream.Length < 2097152)
        {
            var file = new AppFile()
            {
                Content = memoryStream.ToArray()
            };

            _dbContext.File.Add(file);

            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("File", "The file is too large.");
        }
    }

    return Page();
}
```